# How to add custom title to django form fields?

Tags: django

I wanna add my own title to django form fields like this image.

My models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    ad_soyad = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    tarih = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    dogum_tarihi = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    dogum_yeri = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    medeni_hali = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    birinci_evlilik = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    ikinci_evlilik = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    bosanma_tarihi = models.CharField(max_length=255,  default="")
    ogrenim_durumu = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    meslek = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    kan_grubu = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    boy = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    kilo = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    max_kilo = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    max_kilo_tarih = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + '|' + str(self.author)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
    #    return reverse('article-detail', args=(str(self.id)))   bu kod olursa yazı ekledikten sonra o eklenen yazıya gidiyor
         return reverse('home')
```

And my forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
        #field = ('title', 'author')

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'author': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'ad_soyad': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'tarih': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'dogum_tarihi': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'dogum_yeri': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'medeni_hali': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'birinci_evlilik': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'ikinci_evlilik': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'bosanma_tarihi': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'ogrenim_durumu': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'meslek': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'kan_grubu': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'boy': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'kilo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'max_kilo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'max_kilo_tarih': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this on the *model* level, such that this is done for *all* `ModelForm`s for that model with the [**`verbose_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # …,
    dogum_yeri = models.CharField(verbose_name='Doğum Tarihi', max_length=255, default="")
    # …
```

You can also specify the `labels` attribute of the `Meta` of the `ModelForm`, in that case this label of course only applies to *that* specific form, and for other `ModelForm`s for the same model, you thus will have to repeat labeling:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            # …
        }
        labels = {
            'dogum_yeri': 'Doğum Tarihi'
        }
```

I would advise to use `verbose_name` first, and only if a form needs to deviate, specify the `labels` for that specific `ModelForm`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer finally
Adding these code to forms.py

```
 labels = {
        'ad_soyad': ('Ad Soyad'),
        'dogum_tarihi': ('Doğum Tarihi'),
    }
```